# Unity URP shaders invisible

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, urp

I am trying to create shaders for Unity URP.

However, even when I copy the code from [the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@8.2/manual/writing-shaders-urp-basic-unlit-structure.html), the material and the GameObjects it is applied to are invisible and not a constant color that should appear.

I also followed [this tutorial](https://nedmakesgames.medium.com/writing-unity-urp-shaders-with-code-part-1-the-graphics-pipeline-and-you-798cbc941cea), but the result is the same.

When I click on the GameObject inside the hierarchy, the outlines are visible but the object itself is transparent.

I have no idea what is going on and how to fix it because Unity doesn't show an error and I don't know where the error could lie.
The standard shaders work as intended.

EDIT: I think I will use a shader graph and custom functions instead.

EDIT2:
I figured it out. I have to set the Queue to something greater than AlphaTest+50 (eg. 2501).
Can someone explain why this is the case, please?

Answer (score 0):

In the URP renderer, you can set the "Depth Priming Mode" to "Disabled" and the material will be displayed.

I've found the answer from the article you linked, specifically:

> In the settings object, make sure that “Depth Priming Mode” is set to “Disabled” and that the rendering mode is “Forward.”

I couldn't find much documentation about [Depth Priming](https://forum.unity.com/threads/depth-priming-advantages.1132912/), but apparently it's a feature to optimize rendering time.